# Xcode 11 - Warning: Auto Layout Localization: Views without any layout constraints may clip their content or overlap other views

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode11, swift5

I Just downloaded Xcode 11 official version and opened one of my old projects (made with Xcode 10). I don't like AutoLayout so my app doesn't have it, but now the **AutoLayout** option has been removed from the **File** inspector. So I keep getting the following warning for any View in my Storyboard:

```
Auto Layout Localization: Views without any layout 
constraints may clip their content or overlap other views.
```

Anyway, if I run my app everything's fine, Views positions are ok and all I get is just a bunch of those warnings.

I really don't want to use Autolayout in my Xcode projects, so is there a way to silence them? Maybe A hidden Autolayout option somewhere?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you have any luck?

Comment: Not yet, @JamesTSnell  :(

Comment: Worse for me: some labels are missing, but not all. Seems to be the ones with leading edge constraint off left side of view (and trailing off right). And it’s fine on Simulator; but not on device.

Comment: There’s also an issue on Views with margins inside a UITableViewCell, they get messed up and constrained to the right edge :(

Comment: @xscoder, did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: Yes, by using myView.autoResizingMask = .flexibleWidth in the cell’s class, that’s the only workaround i could figure out. anyway the warnings don’t disappear, but at least Views inside a TableView will be ok

Comment: @xscoder, Actually i didn't uncheck "Use AutoLayout" everything is working fine but,there is homescreen like following hierarchy. (ScrollView--UIView--TableView--TableViewCell--UIView--UILabel ).

Comment: @xscoder,When run it it's working fine ,but after one or two days when i open storyboard UIView inside TableViewCell automatically increase width what i set

Comment: @xscoder,Everytime i am again set width for UIView ,is there is any solution for this ?

Comment: yes, do not set margins via the Storyboard -> Size inspector panel, but use the autoresizingMask code in the awakeFromNib() function in the cell’s class

Comment: @xscoder,can i uncheck "Use AutoLayout" ?

Comment: yes, you should do that

Comment: @xscoder, Actually i am using AutoResizingMask in  Xcode 10.2.1 now.if i updated to Xcode 11.is there is any problem with AutoResizingMask ? What i set Previously ?

Comment: @VadlapalliMasthan no, if you set it via code as i said before